# Laravel: Choose different controllers for each request host

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have a Laravel application that needs to service multiple domains, for example, firstdomain.com, seconddomain.com, thirddomain.com.  The logic layer stays the same irrespective of the domain name, but the presentation changes.  Therefore, I want to call a different set of controllers for each domain.  How can I do this?

I have created a middleware that gets the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and sets it as an attribute on the request object, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  Ideally I would set it as a namespace prefix for a group of controllers.

Comment: I've updated the answer below to work in one application. As a sidenote, there is no need to write a custom middleware to pickup the domain into the Request, it's already available as: `Request::server('HTTP_HOST')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your controllers in groups where their domain implementations diverge. You may also have common controllers shared:

```
// Common route
Route::get('about', 'ContentController@about');

// Diverge by domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'foodomain.com'], function () {
    Route::resource('task', 'FooTaskController');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'bardomain.com'], function () {
    Route::resource('task', 'BarTaskController');    
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'loldomain.com'], function () {
    Route::resource('task', 'LolTaskController');
});
```

You could also have these controllers inherit from a common parent `Controller` class, where any shared logic would go

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FooTaskController extends TaskController
```

(...)

```
class BarTaskController extends TaskController
```

(etc...)

Your views can also be organized by domain:

```
\app
\bootstrap
\resources
    \assets
    \lang
    \views
        \foo
            task.blade.php
            home.blade.php
        \bar
            task.blade.php
            home.blade.php
        \lol
            task.blade.php
            home.blade.php
```